# Heroku does not seem to run most recent version of deployed play application

Tags: git, scala, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.2

Yesterday I pushed an update to my Heroku application but the online version does not seem to execute the most recent code. Specifically, a new route I added results in an "Action not found" error [visible here](http://www.wahlversprechen2013.de/json/matches) and the [Akka job I schedule in `Global.onStart`](https://github.com/stheophil/wahlversprechen/blob/master/app/Global.scala) is not started. It is not writing to the log at least.

My [`conf/routes`](https://github.com/stheophil/wahlversprechen/blob/master/conf/routes) file contains line

```
GET     /json/matches               controllers.FeedDaemon.matches()
```

The [corresponding Controller exists](https://github.com/stheophil/wahlversprechen/blob/master/app/controllers/FeedDaemon.scala) and implements this action

```
def matches = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(Cache.get(keyMatches) match {
      case Some(o)  => o.asInstanceOf[String]
      case None => ""
    })
}
```

Needless to say, it works locally. The heroku build did not report any errors and just went through.

I'm using play 2.2.2. My application contains a git submodule and is an sbt multi project build. Heroku detects the git submodule though. If the multi project were the problem, I'd expect build errors or `ClassNotFoundExceptions` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple. In versions before 2.2, the play framework created the startup script at location `target/start` so your Heroku Procfile would have looked like

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS
```

This changed in Play 2.2 and the script is now at location `target/universal/stage/bin/foo` so your Procfile should look like this

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/foo -Dhttp.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS
```

This has also been explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085213/scala-play-2-2-application-crashes-after-deploying-in-heroku-target-start-no-su)

In my case, the old application was started because the build output was never cleaned, so I successfully started the old version after building the new one instead of getting a `target/start` file not found error.

The [heroku-repo](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo) plugin let me clear the build cache, which lead to the `target/start` file not found error, which let to the solution.