# Heroku procfile for scala play app

Tags: postgresql, scala, heroku, playframework

I followed the tutorial on Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#introduction) all the way through successfully.

I then tested getting it working with the same project but a brand new git repo and got it working with Travis.  Had some teething problems, but it works perfectly.

Now I want to get it working on another test project, which uses slick.  I am using a new copy of this repository, have deleted the .git file and re-initialised it:  https://github.com/gupta-himanshu/play-reactive-slick ... the plan being to make that look like the example, then when that works create my own from scratch and then I should be all set up using scala/play/postgres/travis/heroku.  In theory.

So I'm stuck right at the start - I want to make a procfile so that it will deploy to heroku, but according to the previous example, I need to find target/universal/stage/bin/ - but that does not exist.

According to this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085590/2295284 things have previously changed, but the place pointed to in that answer is where I was looking...

I am not using heroku create, because I want the repository on my GitHub account, not just in heroku.

Am I doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `target/universal/stage/bin` dir will be created when you run `sbt stage`. This is done by the sbt-native-package plugin, which is included with the project. Thus, your `Procfile` should look something like this:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/play-reactive-slick -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
```